# Let $G$ be a simple graph with at least $11$ vertices. Prove that either $G$ or its complement $\overline{G}$ must be nonplanar. Connectivity?

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness, planar-graphs

I have seen many solutions to this problem and understand all of them, but I keep thinking they are over simplified because the connectivity of $\overline{G}$ is not addressed.

Solutions in general assume that $G$ is planar, and then we know that $e_G \leq 3(|V| -2) $ holds ($e_G$ is the edge set of $G$, number of vertices of $G$ is $n$).  Then from the complete graph on $n$ vertices we know that $e_{\overline{G}} = \frac{1}{2} n (n-1) - e_G$.
If we then assume that $\overline{G}$ is planar, then sub in the fact that $e_{\overline{G}} \leq 3(|V|-2)$ to get a contradiction.
This is where I don't understand why connectivity is not considered. I know it is possible to have a connected graph that has a disconnected complement, and the inequality $e_{\overline{G}} \leq 3(|V|-2)$ only holds if $\overline{G}$ is connected (or so my lecture notes from class say), so don't we need to consider a case where $\overline{G}$ is disconnected?
And if so how would I approach such a case?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The inequality applies to any planar graph. Just consider the components of the graph.

Comment: I tried that, but my notes say the inequality only holds for graphs with vertex sets larger than or equal to 3.  How do we guarantee that each component would have vertex sets of that size?
I very well may be over thinking this...

Comment: The inequality still holds even if the number of vertices is less than 3. It will just be strict.

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks!

Comment: If you are worried about connectivity, then you could add some more edges to the graph to make it connected, you can do it in a way that does not destroy planarity. Then the bound holds with the additional edges, so it also holds for the starting graph.